# pure CSS - Zebra-stripe table only if it has more than 2 rows

Tags: css

I'm trying to apply a css only zebra stripe style to a table, but only if it has more than 2 rows.

Is this possible with css only? IE9 and upwards is required - so good to go for all css3 selectors.

So far this is what I came up with, but I'm not quite there...

```
Should have Zebra:
<div class="select">
  <table>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<hr>
Should have Zebra:
<div class="select">
  <table>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<hr> Since only 2 elements: shouldnt have Zebra
<div class="select">
  <table>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 1a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 2a</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clickable:nth-child(odd):not(:nth-last-child(2)) {
  background: rgba(230, 230, 230, 1);
  color: red;
}

.clickable:nth-child(even):not(:nth-last-child(1)) {
  background: rgba(180, 180, 180, 1);
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqEWYO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CSS Quantity Queries](http://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css).

Simply add:

```
.clickable:only-child,
.clickable:nth-last-child(2):first-child, 
.clickable:nth-last-child(2):first-child ~ .clickable {
  background: none;
}
```

[Example on Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOzKLZ)

Or you can apply styles only when there 3+ elements:

[Example on Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWXxBg)

Comment: In stead of your last selector you could better use `.clickable:first-child + .clickable:last-child `

Comment: @Harry `.clickable:only-child` and `.clickable:nth-child(odd)` have same weight and it work. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVXWGG

Comment: @AleksandrPetrov:You are correct. My mistake was that I was trying with the code that OP provided in question (it has one more psuedo-class).

Comment: thanks for the ideas. but is it really best practice to add styles on the first hand and remove them afterwards? maybe there's a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: @sangrilaB With quantity queries you can add styles only when there 3+ elements. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWXxBg

Comment: @AleksandrPetrov I like your last solution way more. That's great. Please edit your answer above and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also select (increasing selector weight meantime):

```
/* single tr being first and last */
table tr.clickable:nth-child(odd):first-child:last-child ,
/* last being right after first */  
table tr.clickable:nth-child(odd):first-child +  tr.clickable:nth-child(even):last-child ,
/* first being right before last */
table tr.clickable:nth-child(odd):first-child:nth-last-child(2) {
  background:none;
  color:gray;
}
```

[codepen fork](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bpovpK)

```css
table tr.clickable:nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgba(230, 230, 230, 1);
  color: red;
}

table tr.clickable:nth-child(even) {
  background: rgba(180, 180, 180, 1);
}

table tr.clickable:nth-child(odd):first-child:last-child,
table tr.clickable:nth-child(odd):first-child +  tr.clickable:nth-child(even):last-child,
table tr.clickable:nth-child(odd):first-child:nth-last-child(2) {
  background:none;
  color:gray;
}
```

```html
Should have Zebra:
<div class="select">
  <table>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<hr>
Should have Zebra:
<div class="select">
  <table>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<hr> Since only 2 elements: shouldnt have Zebra
<div class="select">
  <table>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 1a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 2a</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<hr> Since only 1 element: shouldnt have Zebra Css rules
<div class="select">
  <table>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>row 1a</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```